# Vector layer feature destroys after geometry transform

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

I want to get coordinates of a drawn polygon.

```
var myLatLonSquare = vectorLayer.features[0].geometry.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), 
                     new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
```

After zooming, the drawn polygon disappears because of geometry transform.

How can I solve this problem without disappearing drawn polygons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

according to me it cant dissapear. the feature has changed due to the changes in the natural projection. Naturally, the feature might be located to 0,0.

if you want to see your feature:

```
map.zoomToExtent(vectorLayer.getDataExtent());
```

and still you can get your feature as,

```
vectorLayer.features[0]
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Yes you are right, I transformed again feature. Thanks!!!